# How to deploy Update Management to Azure resources the programmatic way

Tags: azure, powershell, updates, patch

I'm currently trying to setup Azure's Update Management Solution to a resource group I have setup. I've read through a lot of documentation on this matter including Microsoft's:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-management

It's pretty straightforward to setup using the GUI however I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to deploy this programatically. I wanted to reach out to the stack community and see if anyone has been able to deploy an environment that uses update management with a code base, or if anyone has found/built a powershell module which can be used to enable update manager on select VMs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to deploy Update Management to Azure automatically with Terraform (step by step):

- Create Automation Account - *resource "azurerm_automation_account"*
- Create Log Analytics Workspace - *resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace"*
- Linked previous created Log Analytics with Automation Account - *resource "azurerm_log_analytics_linked_service*
- Create Log Analytics solution "Updates" - *resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution"* with

  ```
   plan {
   publisher = "Microsoft"
   product   = "OMSGallery/Updates" }
  ```
- Create update schedule using ARM Template Terraform resource - *resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment"* - sample code showed in **4c74356b41** comment above
- Add Microsoft Monitoring Agent extension for VMs you want to be auto updated and added to Update Management, connect them with earlier Log Analytic Workspace - *resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension"*

Comment: This is what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 3):

this piece of arm template should work:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2017-05-15-preview",
    "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/softwareUpdateConfigurations",
    "name": "automationName/softwareUpdateName",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "updateConfiguration": {
            "operatingSystem": "Windows",
            "duration": "PT2H0M",
            "windows": {
                "excludedKbNumbers": [
                    "168934",
                    "168973"
                ],
                "includedUpdateClassifications": "Critical",
                "rebootSetting": "IfRequired"
            },
            "azureVirtualMachines": [
                "/subscriptions/5ae68d89-69a4-454f-b5ce-e443cc4e0067/resourceGroups/myresources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-01",
                "/subscriptions/5ae68d89-69a4-454f-b5ce-e443cc4e0067/resourceGroups/myresources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-02",
                "/subscriptions/5ae68d89-69a4-454f-b5ce-e443cc4e0067/resourceGroups/myresources/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-03"
            ],
            "nonAzureComputerNames": [
                "box1.contoso.com",
                "box2.contoso.com"
            ]
        },
        "scheduleInfo": {
            "frequency": "Hour",
            "startTime": "2017-10-19T12:22:57+00:00",
            "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
            "interval": 1,
            "expiryTime": "2018-11-09T11:22:57+00:00",
            "advancedSchedule": {
                "weekDays": [
                    "Monday",
                    "Thursday"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can use the rest api to find out how to construct `properties` the way you need.

you could use the same `properties` json with invoke-webrequest as a payload, for example, or curl.

Comment: Hey this is awesome! Any documents in particular you used to figure this out which you'd like to recommend?

Comment: Actually stumbled across this repo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.automation.models.windowsproperties.excludedkbnumbers?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: all rest apis are documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/softwareupdateconfigurations

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse. This is a viable solution. Do Update Manager cmdlets exist?

Comment: sorry, not aware of those, but i'm not much into that stuff, so maybe they do

Comment: @4c74356b41 Can you sight any supplemental documentation on using API calls in Azure? Everything I find is referencing using an application and AD. I shouldn't need an application to make a API call. Specifically scheduling updates. Shouldn't I just be able to use my account tenancy?

Comment: just ask a question, comments are not meant for that @Rthomas529

Answer (score 1):

Interacting with "Azure Updates" in powershell is done through the "AzureRMAutomation" cmdlets. For example Scheduling Software updates uses the "New-AzureRmAutomationSoftwareUpdateConfiguration" cmdlet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/new-azurermautomationsoftwareupdateconfiguration?view=azurermps-6.13.0

You should be able to find anything else you want to do in that directory.

I stumbled across this site, which isn't as useful as the above information...

https://sharepointyankee.com/2018/02/26/importing-powershell-modules-into-azure-automation/

This process allows you to download powershell modules from the modules gallery. After doing a simple search for "update". I found 2 modules "xWindowsUpdate" and "PSWindowsUpdate". These don't directly interact with azure update manager, but functionally accomplishes the same result.