# Azure Terraform Automation Schedule

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-automation

I want to create a schedule for azure "patch management" under "automation account.". the document in the Terraform Registry seems to not have enough details? or may be I am missing something. I want to populate following through terraform, any advice?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to create a schedule in automation via Terraform?

Comment: What do you mean by "not enough details" ?

Comment: Look at my answer under this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635285/how-to-deploy-update-management-to-azure-resources-the-programmatic-way

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has removed tech issue 4431 which had an excellent coding example. We don't think this was a good idea, and thus post a code solution into a public git repo. I will later add examples of how to create schedules and assign runbooks to schedules. I have the code, just need to scrub out client specific stuff before pushing to the public repo. This should give you a running start. Happy coding! https://github.com/David-Kent-Consulting/how_to_azure_automationact_with_terraform